# SharpSvn: How can I see Update()'s result?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

When using a simple command line svn client, if you run `update` you can see the changes that were made to your working copy.

I've been trying to do so in SharpSvn (with C#, .Net 3.5), because I need to see if the `Client.Update()` operation caused deletion of files, for example.
I tried using `SvnUpdateResult`, but it returns one item, for the entire folder, with no details I can find. I also can't find anything that looks useful in `SvnUpdateArgs`.

Help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Notify` event, on `SvnUpdateArgs` or on the client instance itself:

```
SvnUpdateArgs ua = new SvnUpdateArgs();
ua.Notify += delegate(object sender, SvnNotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Action);
            Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        };
```