# How can I see Update()'s result in SharpSvn using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sharpsvn

I am trying to automate the update function in subversion wuth SharpSvn.
When using a simple command line svn client, if you run update you can see the changes that were made to your working copy.

I've been trying to do so in SharpSvn (with VB.NET,  2.0), because I need to see if the Client.Update operation caused deletion of files, for example.
I've found an answer to this same question for C# and tried to understand and translate the code but have not succeeded. I think there is something I am missing that may be obvious to the ones who were happy with this answer. If you can't answer my main question, I'de be happy to know what the second line in the following code is doing.

The C# answer:

```
SvnUpdateArgs ua = new SvnUpdateArgs();
ua.Notify += delegate(object sender, SvnNotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Action);
            Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
        };
```

[SharpSvn: How can I see Update()'s result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767081/sharpsvn-how-can-i-see-updates-result)

Answer (score -1):

All you must to do is declare a new SvnUpdateArgs then add a handler to the Notify envent of de svnUpdatArgs by simply adding a delegate or an AddressOf method or directly a sub method if you are in vs2013. Example:

Dim ua As New SvnUpdateArgs()
            AddHandler ua.Notify, Sub(sender As Object, e As SvnNotifyEventArgs)
                                    'TODO:
                                  End Sub

Comment: Please add a phrase to explain.