# How to write the SharpSvn.Update Result in file?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I want to print the modified/removed/deleted/added files details in text file using SharpSvn.Update

```
 SvnUpdateResult result;
 client.Update(path,out result);
```

But this code only returns the revision number not the changes details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharpSvn: How can I see Update()'s result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767081/sharpsvn-how-can-i-see-updates-result)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more details on what the update did, you should hook the `Notify` event. SharpSvn provides this event on both the `SvnClient` and the optional SvnUpdateArgs class instance that you pass to `.Update()`

See [SharpSvn: How can I see Update()'s result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767081/sharpsvn-how-can-i-see-updates-result)